# How to save and extract session data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I save some data in session on my verify controller then I extract this session data into user_activity model and insert session data into activity table. My problem is only username data saved in session and I can get and insert only username data after extracting session on model. I am new in Codeigniter. For this reason It’s very difficult to find out the problem. I am trying several days finding the problem. But unfortunately I can’t. So please, anyone help me. Thanks

VerifyLogin controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
session_start();
class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
   $this->load->model('user_activity','',TRUE);
  }

 function index()
 {
   //This method will have the credentials validation
   $this->load->library('form_validation');

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
     //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
     $this->load->view('login_view');
   }
   else
   {
     //Go to private area
     redirect('home', 'refresh');
   }
 }

 function check_database($password)
 {
   //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
   $username = $this->input->post('username');
   $vercode = $this->input->post('vercode');

   //query the database
   $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

   // ip address
   $ip_address= $this->user_activity->get_client_ip();

   //Retrieving session data and other data
   $captcha_code=$_SESSION['captcha'];
   $user_agent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

   if($result && $captcha_code == $vercode)
   {
     $sess_array = array();
     foreach($result as $row)
     {
       $sess_array = array(
         'username' => $row->username,
           'user_agent' => $row->user_agent,
           'ip_address' => $row->ip_address,
       );
       $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);

        //insert user activity
       $this->user_activity->activity();
     }
     return TRUE;
   }
   else
   {
     $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
     return false;
   }
 }
}
?>
```

user_activity model:

```
    <?php
    Class User_activity extends CI_Model
    {
     function activity()
     {
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
       {
         $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
       //  $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];

           $data = array(
                  'session_id'=>"",
                  'ip_address'=>$session_data['ip_address'],
                  'user_agent'=>$session_data['user_agent'],
                  'username'=>$session_data['username'],
                  'time_stmp'=>Now(),
                  'user_data'=>$session_data['username']."Logged in Account"
                );
        $this->db->insert('user_activity',$data);        
       }
       else
       {
          return  false;
       }

       // Function to get the client ip address
    function get_client_ip() {
        $ipaddress = '';
        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
        else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
        else if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        else
            $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

        return $ipaddress;
       }
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: do $session_data = $this->session->set_userdata($sess_array); cfr. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html section Adding Custom Session Data

Comment: See Example:
http://devgambit.com/how-to-store-and-get-session-value-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can set data to session simply like this in Codeigniter:

```
$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_userdata(array(
    'user_id'  => $user->uid,
    'username' => $user->username,
    'groupid'  => $user->groupid,
    'date'     => $user->date_cr,
    'serial'   => $user->serial,
    'rec_id'   => $user->rec_id,
    'status'   => TRUE
));
```

and you can get it like this:

```
$u_rec_id = $this->session->userdata('rec_id');
$serial = $this->session->userdata('serial');
```

Comment: I load session in auto load. username save successfully but other data don't save.

Answer (score 17):

First you have load session library.

```
$this->load->library("session");
```

You can load it in auto load, which I think is better.

To set session

```
$this->session->set_userdata("SESSION_NAME","VALUE");
```

To extract Data

```
$this->session->userdata("SESSION_NAME");
```

Answer (score 6):

initialize the Session class in the constructor of controller using

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

for example :

```
 function __construct()
   {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
    $this->load->model('user_activity','',TRUE);
    $this->load->library('session');
   }
```

Comment: I load session in auto load. username save successfully but other data don't save.

Comment: @user2365514, I'm facing same issue as you commented. Could you please tell me how actually you solved?

Answer (score 4):

In codeigniter we are able to store session values in a database.
In the config.php file make the sess_use_database variable `true`

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
```

and create a ci_session table in the database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

For more details and reference, [click here](http://www.crashcoder.com/saving-session-data-to-a-database-in-codeigniter/)

Answer (score 2):

CI Session Class track information about each user while they browse site.Ci Session class generates its own session data, offering more flexibility for developers.

**Initializing a Session**

To initialize the Session class manually in our controller constructor use following code.

**Adding Custom Session Data**

We can add our custom data in session array.To add our data to the session array involves passing an array containing your new data to this function.

```
$this->session->set_userdata($newarray);
```

Where $newarray is an associative array containing our new data.

```
$newarray = array( 'name' => 'manish', 'email' => 'manish@our-site.com'); $this->session->set_userdata($newarray);
```

**Retrieving Session**

$session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');

Above function returns FALSE (boolean) if the session array does not exist.

**Retrieving All Session Data**

$this->session->all_userdata()

I have taken reference from http://www.tutsway.com/codeigniter-session.php.

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter you can store your session value as single or also in array format as below:

If you want store any user’s data in session like userId, userName, userContact etc,  then you should store in array:

```
<?php
$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_userdata(array(
'userId'  => $user->userId,
'userName' => $user->userName,
'userContact '  => $user->userContact 
)); 
?>
```

Get in details with Example Demo :

http://devgambit.com/how-to-store-and-get-session-value-in-codeigniter/