# Is it correct to use APC cache to store information that is linked to a particular session?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, caching, apc

I have a huge multidimensional array with configurations that i want to keep in memory.
Those configurations define were the user can go in the webpage.

Initially i tought APC would cache the data only during a particular session. But quickly i realize that I was wrong.

So I come up with this idea.

**#Codeigniter sets a session_id**

```
$sessionId = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
```

**#and with that session_id i can prefix each key stored with apc cache**

```
$key = $session_id . '_' . 'config';
```

**#then i serialize array of data**

```
$data = serialize($configurations_array);
```

**#LOAD APC CACHE LIBRARY**

```
$this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'apc', 'backup' => 'file'));
```

**#SET DATA AND CACHE LIFETIME USING THE SAME SESSION DURATION FROM CONFIG FILE**

```
$this->cache->save($key, $data_serialized, $this->config->item('sess_expiration'));
```

**#READ DATA FROM CACHE**

```
$cached_configurations = $this->cache->get($key);
var_dump($cached_configurations);
```

**#REMOVE DATA ON LOGOUT**

```
apc_delete($key);
```

What do you have to say about this?

## EDIT

I forgot to mention that I tested it and it works fine.

Comment: What is the data you're storing? (Can it be recreated if it drops out of the cache?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you put the data linked to the session in the session itself (obviously not in the session cookie, but on the server side)? I guess CodeIgniter provides some facility to store session data on the server side (without using APC).

Your hand-crafted solution may work but seems an unconventional way to solve a very standard problem. In plain PHP I just use `$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar'` after a `session_start()` to store session data on the server side. The session cookie only stores the session ID.

[This article](http://www.moreofless.co.uk/using-native-php-sessions-with-codeigniter) explains how to use native PHP sessions with CodeIgniter. Native PHP sessions are backed by plain files, purged on a regular basis. If the session data is very large, you may consider [storing it in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18886278/671092).

Whatever solution you choose, my advice is to keep it simple and use standard solutions.

Comment: thanks for sharing. I had to replace the codeigniter session with native session but with this solution i were able to store those 1500 characters in the session. It's much better than using the APC handcrafted solution above hehe