# best way to store session in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I want use **session** in my website but I can't find best way to store them, **codeigniter** offers *files*, *database* and so on. but which is best??

I use file with this config:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = '_s';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 0;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

but i get this error:

```
Unable to create file ./_s\ci_sessionecc1dccdd1118e02ee956dde8aadaf7f1116c1ac because No such file or directory
```

I must use *database* ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save and extract session data in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547489/how-to-save-and-extract-session-data-in-codeigniter)

Comment: i know how use session, i want know how config session drivers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find the best way is to create a cache/session/ folder in your systems directory is more safer I put important things like logs and cache in system rather than application folder.

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Config.php

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'somekey';

$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'cache/sessions/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

I also would autoload sessions my self

**application/config/autoload.php**

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');`

Usage Example

On login form_validation success part

```
$data = array(
'is_logged' => true,
'username' => $this->input->post('username')
);

$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

One you set your data then after login can get sessions `$this->session->userdata('username')` etc

Comment: don't for get when you logout you can use codeigniter session unset or destroy etc.

Comment: Read the user guide link more it will explain more about session unset and destroy. added link

Comment: you mean use $this->session->unset_userdata() ?? i use it right now

Comment: Only use unset when you need to clear some session like $this->session->unset_userdata('username') etc. Else to get data once session set use example $this->session->userdata('username')

Comment: Actual question is about "best way to store session in codeigniter", as there are many ways to store session, so which one is best from them?

Comment: @ImranQamer I have for me the best way please read first lines