# CodeIgniter Session stored on "files", cannot see the sessions

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

We have been storing sessions in file drivers but sess_save_path was set to null. And when we had to search sessions, we did not find it on the server. After that, I have set the sess_save_path to these values:

`$sessionPath = FCPATH."/session/";`

`$sessionPath = ('localhost'==$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path_to_folder/session/' : dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/path_to_folder/session/'`

Doing so,

1. On localhost I did get an empty file that was generated before logging in to the system, but after logging in there was no other file generated.
2. At the server, there was no file generated.

Have I missed anything?

Thanks.

Comment: "*Have I missed anything?*" - I think yes, you missed reading [the docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#files-driver) :-)  First of all, **absolutely** do not save sessions under your document root, as clearly explained in the docs.  Second of all, once you pick a non-public directory, you need to set permissions and ownership on that directory, so that your web server can write files there - again as explained in the docs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [best way to store session in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064958/best-way-to-store-session-in-codeigniter)

Comment: @Don'tPanic I am not panicking (pun intended.)... I have used the DocumentRoot and appended another path to browse to the desired folder to store the session. And yes, the session folder has all the appropriate permission, we even tried with the full access (777), for  testing obviously, and even then the folder was empty...

Thanks...

Comment: @Don'tPanic, yes tried using BASEPATH method too, all the methods I've tried pointed at the same path

Comment: First of all, **absolutely** do not save sessions under your document root, as clearly explained in the docs. "*the DocumentRoot and appended another path*" is under the docroot.