# how to use session in login system and implement logout in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication, logout

New in codeigniter learning it and stuck on the session for codeigniter.
I am working on a login system the login part is working good but now i have to add session and logout and include my other pages in to that session so i can restrict someone to direct access that page. so how i implement session & logout in my code.

This is the Controller

```
<?php
class LoginController extends CI_controller
        {
            public function index()
        {
            $this->load->view('header2');
            $this->load->view('login');
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }
            public function checklogin()
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username' ,'Username', 'required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password' ,'Password', 'required|callback_verifyUser');

                if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
                    $this->load->view('header2');
                    $this->load->view('login');
                    $this->load->view('footer');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        redirect('HomeController/index');
                    }
                }
                    public function verifyUser()
                    {
                        $name = $this->input->post('username');
                        $pass = $this->input->post('password');

                        $this->load->model('LoginModel');

                        if($this->LoginModel->login($name, $pass))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $this->form_validation->set_message('verifyUser','Incorrect Email or Pass');
                            return false;
                        }
                        redirect('LoginController/checklogin');
                    }
            }
```

The model is like this

```
<?php
        class LoginModel extends CI_model
        {
            public function login($name, $pass)
            {
                $this->db->select('name,pass');
                $this->db->from('members');
                $this->db->where('name',$name);
                $this->db->where('pass',$pass);     

                $query = $this->db->get();

                if($query->num_rows() == 1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

The View is

```
                  <html>
                    <head>
                    <title></title>
                </head>
                <body>
                <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                <?php echo form_open('LoginController/checklogin'); ?>
                UserName: 
                <input type="text" name="username" /><br/>
                password:
                <input type="text" name="password" />
                <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" />
                </form>
                </body>
                </html>
```

login is working correctly need a session and logout in this.

Comment: @Deep Parekh sir if you are not busy the need a guidance on this...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save and extract session data in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547489/how-to-save-and-extract-session-data-in-codeigniter)

Comment: @Meenesh Jain sir i tried online example but can't understand that session system my login system is working good only want to add a session on it and logout in this.

Comment: see the answer and reference link use that code in your code above integrate both codes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) First **Include** the **Library**:

> $this->load->library('session');

2) **Store** the **data** in **array** which you want to store in session :

```
$data= array(
                   'username'  => 'username',
                   'password'     => 'password',
                   'email'=>'emailid'
                   'logged_in' => 'login id'
               );
```

3) **Store** this **data** in **session**:

```
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

You can **use this data any time** for example if you want loginid from session you can write:

```
$loginid= $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
```

**When LOGOUT :**

```
$this->session->unset_userdata(array("username"=>"","logged_in"=>"","password"=>"","email"=>""));
$this->session->sess_destroy();
redirect('loginpage');
```

> If you don't want to direct access the pages create one model and add this
>   code in it and auto load that model.

```
public function valid_allowed()//check user is login or not
    {
        $session = $this->session->userdata('username'); //here you can take loginid, email whatever you store in session
        if(!$session)
        {
            redirect('login');
        }
    }
```

**To auto load** that **model**

Go to application->config->autoload.php: this line:

```
$autoload['model'] = array('model name');
```

**Change you model:**

```
<?php
        class LoginModel extends CI_model
        {
            public function login($name, $pass)
            {
                $this->db->select('name,pass');
                $this->db->from('members');
                $this->db->where('name',$name);
                $this->db->where('pass',$pass);     

                $query = $this->db->get();

                if($query->num_rows() == 1)
                {
                    $row=$query->row();
                    $data=array(
                    'username'=>$row->u_username,
                    'id'=>$row->id,
                    'email'=>$row->email
                    'password'=>$row->u_password);
                    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Change your verifyUser function:**

```
 public function verifyUser()
                        {
                            $name = $this->input->post('username');
                            $pass = $this->input->post('password');

                            $this->load->model('LoginModel');
                            $result=$this->LoginModel->login($name, $pass))
                         if(!$result)                   
                         {

             $this->form_validation->set_message('verifyUser','Incorrect Email or Pass');
                                return false;
                     redirect('LoginController/checklogin');

                        }
                        else
                        {   
                           redirect('dashboard');   //user is valid so goto dashboard
                        }
}
```

Comment: sir, i don't know where i put this data in my example so,, can you help me over that...  sir...

Comment: see my edited code "Change your model" change the data name as per your data

Comment: if login done then try to print some session data like username or anything to verify....

Comment: how to print ...  i mean on dashboard i print it or echo $username,,  echo $id like that sir..?

Comment: read my answer i have already told. $username= $this->session->userdata('username'); echo $username;exit;

Comment: sorry sir but ...still can't print it

Comment: make sure your data name is correct like username, pass,email etc.

Comment: try to print you $data in model and see the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86858/discussion-between-ankit-suthar-and-deep-parekh).

Comment: sir how to restrict direct acess of other page of site..  means how to use session on the view pages to restrict direct acess of it..  user can only reach that page threw login...

Answer (score 1):

once the login is successful, set user id in session like this

```
$this->session->set_userdata("id",$variable);
```

this can be done any where, but for u, do in model

```
if($query->num_rows() == 1)
{         
    // set session here and then return true.
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
 }
```

so when ever you want to check if the session exists or not, do something like this

```
if(!$this->session->userdata("id")){
    // redirect the user to login page
}
```

write the above code in constructor of all the controllers in which u need login. make sure u dont check for session data in login controller.

Comment: thanks for the answer but can you help me where i put this code specific on my code.

Comment: i ve mentioned above. keep it in model where u r checking for num_rows()

Comment: i can't enter threw login the redirect thing is may be working  but i can't login now....   inserting a correct mail id and pass i can't go threw it.

Comment: like this    
  if($query->num_rows() == 1)
{         
$query = $query->row();
   $this->session->set_userdata("id",$query->id);
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
 }

Comment: same problem sir...   can't login with correct data.

Comment: have u kept separate login controller? r u ve merger login with other controllers?

Answer (score 1):

See simple procedure to use session in CI is

> include this library to perform session or else session wont work

```
  $this->load->library('session');
```

> to save data in session you need to create a array of data and then use `set_userdata()` to save session data

```
 $newdata = array(
                   'username'  => 'example_user',
                   'email'     => 'someone@some-site.com',
                   'logged_in' => 1
               );

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

there are multiple things in session which you should remember

> See reference [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)  and [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you keep getting this bug, just update  your Session file on:

> System/libraries/Session/Session.php

with the most recent file online.