# Codeigniter sessions with database not working in localhost but working in server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am tring to  get the session information in home page on my localhost but I am not getting it. But getting this information on my server.

In Localhost:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bK0q.png)

In Server:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5WvO.png)

I am trying to get with following code:-

```html
print_r($this->session);
```

Comment: pls put some code there instead of image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086348/how-i-can-set-a-session-in-codeigniter-3-database

Comment: you can check this question for getting the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547489/how-to-save-and-extract-session-data-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

You can set data to session simply like this in Codeigniter:

```
$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_userdata(array(
    'user_id'  => $user->uid,
    'username' => $user->username,
    'groupid'  => $user->groupid,
    'date'     => $user->date_cr,
    'serial'   => $user->serial,
    'rec_id'   => $user->rec_id,
    'status'   => TRUE
));
```

and you can get it like this:

```
$u_rec_id = $this->session->userdata('rec_id');
$serial = $this->session->userdata('serial');
```

Comment: But in server its working fine....why this error is occured in localhost